# Python flask stream not updating

Tags: python, flask, event-sourcing

I'm trying to stream some data, to update progress bar on my website. For testing I'm running this:

```
@application.route('/api/stream', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stream():
    def event_stream():
        n = 0
        while True:
            yield "data: %s\n\n" % n
            n += 1
            time.sleep(1)
    return Response(event_stream(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

@application.route('/api/output')
def index():
    return """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
        var source=new EventSource("/api/stream");
        source.onmessage=function(event) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
        };
        source.update=function(event) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
        };
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Data</h1>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

and on my website I've got post function:

```
$.post("//mywebsite.com/api/stream", {"some": 'ss'}, function(data) {
    alert(data)
})
```

And when I run this POST (above) then I'm opening mywebsite.com/api/output and it displays only:

Data

But when after a while I stop my flask app, on the website I'm getting:

```
Data
0
1
2
```

Why It's not updating live but only when I stop flask app?

Comment: `$.post` does not return partial/live data. It return only the full body after the connection is closed.

Comment: I need more details if you want help. For example, where in your website you have that `$.post` called?